# Design an algorithm to determine whether a digraph has a unique topological ordering

Tags: graph-algorithm

Design an algorithm to determine whether a digraph has a unique topological ordering...since I know a digraph has a unique topological ordering if and only if there is a directed edge between each pair of consecutive vertices in the topological order..but how can I design a algorithm to determine that?

Answer (score 0):

Unique topological ordering means that there is only one sequence of the sub-tasks in which the complete task can be done. It means that there is no choice and hence the graph should be a list i.e. the one task should depend on the other which depends on other and so on.